# Allow User to change input selection in selectizeInput

Tags: shiny

This app is creating a vector of standardised names which I create given some user input (number of channels and replicates). An example of the standard names given the number of channels = 4 and and replicates = 1 is as follows:

```
c("rep1_C0","rep1_C1","rep1_C2","rep1_C3")
```

I would like to allow the user to replace the value of the selection with their own custom value. For example to change the input "rep1_C0" to "Control_rep1". And then for it to then update the reactive vector in question. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(column(5, numericInput("chans","# Channels",value = 4, min = 1)),
                 column(5, numericInput("reps","# Replicates",value = 1,min = 1))
        ),
        uiOutput("selectnames")
      ),

      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("testcols")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {



    standardNames <- reactive({ 
      paste("rep",rep(1:input$reps,each = input$chans),"_",
                           rep(paste("C",0:(input$chans - 1), sep = ""),input$reps),sep = "")
    })

    output$selectnames <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput("selectnames", "Change Names", choices = standardNames(),
                       options = list(maxOptions = input$reps * input$chans))
})

    ## output 

   output$testcols <-  renderTable({
      standardNames()
    })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there some kind of option I can pass in the options sections that will allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `selectizeInput` you can set `options = list(create = TRUE)` to allow the user to add levels to the selection list, but I don't think that is what you want.

Instead, here is code that generates a text input box for each of the standard names, and allows the user to enter a label for them. It uses `lapply` and `sapply` to loop over each value and generate/read the inputs.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(column(5, numericInput("chans","# Channels",value = 4, min = 1)),
               column(5, numericInput("reps","# Replicates",value = 1,min = 1))
      ),
      uiOutput("setNames")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("testcols")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {



  standardNames <- reactive({ 
    paste("rep",rep(1:input$reps,each = input$chans),"_",
          rep(paste("C",0:(input$chans - 1), sep = ""),input$reps),sep = "")
  })

  output$setNames <- renderUI({

    lapply(standardNames(), function(thisName){
      textInput(paste0("stdName_", thisName)
                , thisName
                , thisName)
    })

  })

  labelNames <- reactive({
    sapply(standardNames()
           , function(thisName){
             input[[paste0("stdName_", thisName)]]
           })
  })

  ## output 

  output$testcols <-  renderTable({
    data.frame(
      stdName = standardNames()
      , label = labelNames()
    )
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you want to hide the list unless the user wants to add labels, you can use a simple checkbox, like this, which hides the label making list until the use checks the box to show it.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(column(5, numericInput("chans","# Channels",value = 4, min = 1)),
               column(5, numericInput("reps","# Replicates",value = 1,min = 1))
      )
      , checkboxInput("customNames", "Customize names?")
      , uiOutput("setNames")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("testcols")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {



  standardNames <- reactive({ 
    paste("rep",rep(1:input$reps,each = input$chans),"_",
          rep(paste("C",0:(input$chans - 1), sep = ""),input$reps),sep = "")
  })

  output$setNames <- renderUI({

    if(!input$customNames){
      return(NULL)
    }

    lapply(standardNames(), function(thisName){
      textInput(paste0("stdName_", thisName)
                , thisName
                , thisName)
    })

  })

  labelNames <- reactive({

    if(!input$customNames){
      return(standardNames())
    }

    sapply(standardNames()
           , function(thisName){
             input[[paste0("stdName_", thisName)]]
           })
  })

  ## output 

  output$testcols <-  renderTable({
    data.frame(
      stdName = standardNames()
      , label = labelNames()
    )
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Alternatively, if you think the user may want to only change one or a small number of labels, here is a way to allow them to choose which standard name they are applying a label to:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(column(5, numericInput("chans","# Channels",value = 4, min = 1)),
               column(5, numericInput("reps","# Replicates",value = 1,min = 1))
      )
      , uiOutput("setNames")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("testcols")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  vals <- reactiveValues(
    labelNames = character()
  )


  standardNames <- reactive({ 
    out <- paste("rep",rep(1:input$reps,each = input$chans),"_",
                 rep(paste("C",0:(input$chans - 1), sep = ""),input$reps),sep = "")
    vals$labelNames = setNames(out, out)

    return(out)
  })

  output$setNames <- renderUI({

    list(
      h4("Add labels")
      , selectInput("nameToChange", "Standard name to label"
                    , names(vals$labelNames))
      , textInput("labelToAdd", "Label to apply")
      , actionButton("makeLabel", "Set label")
    )

  })

  observeEvent(input$makeLabel, {
    vals$labelNames[input$nameToChange] <- input$labelToAdd
  })

  ## output 

  output$testcols <-  renderTable({
    data.frame(
      stdName = standardNames()
      , label = vals$labelNames
    )
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but this solution is a bit ugly when the number of names is large. Is there a way to make this into a 2 input approach i.e one with standard names and one where i can change the name selected?

Comment: See update for ways to either hide the list when it is unwanted or to change just one label at a time (My guess, however, is that if users want to change one label, they will want to change lots of labels, and having to select each from the list may be cumbersome.)